# Flutter - Redirect to login in screen after update from the app store

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I redirect to the Login screen after updating the app from Test Flight/ App Store.
Version 1 of the app does not have a login. New downloads are directed to the Login Screen, but updates are not redirecting to the login screen.

In main:

```
initialUser == null || displaySplashImage
          ? Builder(
              builder: (context) => Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Center(
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/ios.png',
                    width: 250,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          : currentUser!.loggedIn
              ? NavBarPage()
              : LoginWidget(),
```

I want to put a redirect in the home screen, but it throws an error. What is the best way to redirect them to the login screen after the new update?

```
 if (currentUser!.loggedIn != true) {
      print('user is not logged in');

      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => LoginWidget(),
          ));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to save the version of the app in which user logged in, and when opening the app check if current version is equal to the previous one, and if not, set logged in to false.

Comment: The previous version does not have a login. The update is not running main in the way I expected. It works fine on new downloads.